# Phaser javascript white screen problem in game

Tags: javascript, project, social-gaming

When I am creating the game in the web system ....It works fine . But when I m testing it on android ...It loads first white screen the n game loader and then game lobby. But i want to remove this white screen problem before loader of game . So let me know if you have any kind of ideas aboout phaser frameworkl of javascript projects for games

Let me know

Comment: Please show some code. We can't reproduce or understand clearly your problem just with that description.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.